# Symfony custom configuration - namespace issue

Tags: php, symfony

Following the advice posted at [Loading custom config file for app in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765136/loading-custom-config-file-for-app-in-symfony2) I stucked into namespace issue.

In `\src\AppBundle\DependencyInjection` I have two files:

**AppExtension.php:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Tests\Fixtures\Entity;
use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 */
class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter('kh', $config['kh']);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('general.yml'); # another file of yours

    }
}
```

and **Configuration.php**:

```
<?
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
         $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('kh');

         $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->arrayNode('tags')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('name')->isRequired()->end();
                    ->scalarNode('role')->isRequired()->end();
                    ->scalarNode('priority')->isRequired()->end();
                    ->scalarNode('label')->isRequired()->end();
                ->end();
            ->end();
        ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

It seems that I make some kind of mistake naming the files as executing:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

results in:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration' not found in /var/www/dev.investmentopportunities.pl/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php on line 22
>       [2015-08-02 10:39:36] php.EMERGENCY: Fatal Error: Class 'AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration' not found {"type":1,"file":"/var/www/dev.investmentopportunities.pl/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php","line":22,"level":6143,"stack":[]}

Unluckily I have a problem with finding the error on my own. I have tried to rename files but still the error occurs. Could you please advice what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

As sugested by @San Thapa I have tried also to remove "use" command. This results in:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration' not found in /var/www/dev.investmentopportunities.pl/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php on line 21
>       [2015-08-02 12:05:27] php.EMERGENCY: Fatal Error: Class 'AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration' not found {"type":1,"file":"/var/www/dev.investmentopportunities.pl/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php","line":21,"level":6143,"stack":[]}
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]
>     Attempted to load class "Configuration" from namespace "AppBundle\Dependenc
>     yInjection".
>     Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Depend
>     encyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DependencyInjecti
>     on\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\DependencyInjection\Co
>     nfiguration", "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\Bundle\TestB
>     undle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\D
>     ependencyInjection\Configuration", "Genemu\Bundle\FormBundle\DependencyInje
>     ction\Configuration", "Doctrine\ORM\Configuration", "Doctrine\DBAL\Configur
>     ation", "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DependencyInjection\Configurat
>     ion", "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration",
>      "Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Symfony
>     \Bundle\AsseticBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Sensio\Bundle\Fr
>     ameworkExtraBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "PUGX\AutocompleterB
>     undle\DependencyInjection\Configuration", "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Depen
>     dencyInjection\Configuration", "FOS\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\Configur
>     ation" or "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration
>     "?

What seems a bit strange acessing the webpage from browser does not result in any error.

Comment: No need to use the namespace in this case as both the files resides on same directory and enclosed by same namespace, you can use it directly without `use` statement.

Comment: Hi thanks for clue. I tried it at beginning but still it caused error.

Comment: If you are running the project on development environment try clearing cache on development too. Clearing cache has worked for me most of the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added to first line of Configuration.php:

```
<?php
```

and also remove semicolons:

```
$rootNode
        ->children()
        ->arrayNode('tags')
        ->prototype('array')
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('name')->isRequired()->end()
                ->scalarNode('role')->isRequired()->end()
                ->scalarNode('priority')->isRequired()->end()
                ->scalarNode('label')->isRequired()->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

I'm not sure about structure... Maybe you forgot add one more end()...

Comment: The <? instead of <?php will be probably be the source of problem. I will check it tomorrow nevertheless thanks for clue. Sometimes the easiest errors are the hardest to find out.